# Using m2eclipse for multiple projects with parent pom.xml

Tags: eclipse, maven-3

I have multiple maven projects with their individual pom.xml's an a parent pom.xml.

```
my_workspace
├── application-project
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│           └── ...
│       └── test
│           └── ...
├── common-project
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│           └── ...
│       └── test
│           └── ...
└── pom.xml
```

Now, from Eclipse, I can right click on common-project or application-project, I see Run As Maven... options there. But when I need to run a specific goal for all the projects, i.e. which is in the parent pom.xml, I don't understand how to go about it, if not using command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you have appropriate plug-in, if not already having, [install m2eclipse plugin first](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/installing-m2eclipse.html)

> Run > Run Configuration > Maven Build

Double click[*], choose the project, put down the goals, put down profile if any.

Fron next time use this (will be available in drop down) to execute your own goals.

[*] The form that opens here has all the capability to construct a maven command that you can run from command line. You might need to play around a bit to get what you *actually* wanted.

---

*Updated as question was modified*:

OK, so your `parent project` is your workspace folder. worry not.

> Run > Run Configuration > Maven Build

Double click, **browse filesystem and select the workspace folder**, put down the goals, put down profile if any. I have just tested it. It works.

---

Yet another way, as OP found out, that you can click `variables...` button beneath the text-field for `Base Directory` and choose `workspace_loc` to point to your `workspace directory` as the base directory for Maven build.

Comment: well, i need to select multiple projects since the whole workspace has my projects. How do i do that?

Comment: you want to run one maven command on all the projects? Why not execute the command on parent project. Ultimately all the children will be processed as per their effective pom.

Comment: oh..my bad, i have show the tree wrong, i have updated my question.

Comment: the problem is, you cannot select the base directory as the workspace it self.

Comment: @zengr oh. you can. I just switched my project workspace to make parent project folder, the workspace directory. It worked. As mentioned in updated answer. Didn't it for you?

Comment: yup, `${workspace_loc}` worked. Now, I just need to figure out what should be the goal and profiles. I a n00b at maven!

Comment: agree. There are just a little too much moving pieces in maven, ant was a little straight fwd. You suggest any quick how-to (url) on maven goals/profiles?

Comment: @zengr Maven profiles are just a way to say different build conditions on different environments. Like the standard approach is to have 3 profiles, `dev`, `test` and `prod` they have different properties like dev & test may have debug ON while prod will have only FATAL log on. dev may have file storage in `C:\files` but prod might point to `Amazon S3` for things like that. see here http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html And Goals are basically instructing Maven plugins to what to do to `build`, `package`, `deploy` or may be something like `run:jetty` for srvr

Comment: @zengr  This is probably the best resource. You may not read line by line, but if you are able to start with Maven. You may look into this book whenever you get stuck. http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/public-book.html

Comment: @zengr "Now, I just need to figure out what should be the goal and profiles. I a n00b at maven!" I didn't see this. Try with goal `install` and leave profile field blank.

Comment: `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3:install (default-install): Goal requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this build.` But there is a pom.xml in the workspace folder. When I do a `mvn clean install` in the same place, it works fine.

Comment: @zengr ... and browsing the directory does not work either? It's easier to switch workspace `File > Switch Workspace > Other...` to a directory above your parent folder. And then `File > import > General > Maven Project` and import the parent project. This will make life much easier. BTW, you do not need to write `mvn` in goal just enter `clean install` it will be taken care of.